# is there a way to generate dummy content for paragraphs?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I am working in Drupal 8. Is there any way, with devel, to generate dummy content for paragraphs to visually get a feel for how things would look? Is there a module or script to accomplish that might work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any.

Comment: Just a note: Not sure why this is flagged as off-topic, seems very on-topic to me.

Answer (score 2):

Paragraphs need a host entity to work normally iirc, so if the paragraph is attached to a node type through a reference field, I've had success creating them with Drupal console's node generator: `drupal create:nodes` which seems to populate all the fields it can.

Beware though: I've had to `drupal create:terms` first to generate a few taxonomy terms, or else the node generation takes ages! Your laptop may take off before the process finishes ;)